# TSQL Count 'Where' Condition

Tags: t-sql, count, conditional-statements, distinct

How do I implement the 'meaning' of the following psuedo-SQL statement:

```
COUNT(distinct id where attribute1 > 0)
```

In other words, how do I make conditional, distinct counting statements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Well, if you can filter the entire query, then LittleBobbyTables already has [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11676249/621962) for you. If not, you can get that column like so:

```
count(distinct case when attribute1 > 0 then id end) -- implicit null-else, iirc
```

Comment: I needed it as part of a query. What is wrong with using it in an aggregate function?

Comment: +1, and you do remember correctly: when `ELSE` is omitted, `ELSE NULL` is implied. On a different note, I don't really understand this "performance concern" with regard to conditional aggregating. I mean, what are alternatives to `CASE` in an aggregate function (for instance, when your query needs to return both conditional and unconditional count)?

Comment: I see, but you've already stipulated that in your answer, so your last statement sounds as if someone might be annoyed with a *perfectly legitimate* use of conditional aggregation. I just wanted to make it clear if you really meant that. And in general, I agree with you that this thing *can* be abused, like anything else.

Comment: I've occasionally had a legitimate need for this kind of logic, and it usually involves multiple aggregates in the same SELECT, like "count where FieldX is not null" and then "count where FieldX is null" to compare the counts with each other, or "count where FieldY = 2" and "count where FieldY = 3" etc., again, to compare the counts.  And I think that's what CodeKingPP was after.  I liked this solution because it's what I usually do in these situations, and the comments between Canon and AndriyM are helpful to point out the potential misunderstanding or misuse.

Answer (score 6):

You pretty much had it:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [ID]) AS DistinctID
FROM YourTable
WHERE attribute1 > 0
```